# What is the advantage of using Image Load/Store over texture samplers in compute shader?

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

I can't see any advantage of image load/store.

I have pretty complex compute shader calculating global illumination. I implemented both variants equally - texture based and image based. I see performance drop when using images.

Also, it is impossible - maybe only on AMD - to read and write to texture at the same shader. I don't know why is that impossible, but what are then the advantages of using images?

My shader source for image load/store variant: https://gist.github.com/achlubek/c96a7f6f4271c5978ef2

Comment: Well, I think you answered it yourself: You can write to images with shader instructions, but not to textures. So you would use images if you need to write to them in the shader code.

Comment: Properly defined memory coherence would be the primary advantage. Samplers aren't an ideal fit for the compute shader model of doing things, they're great for the traditional render pipeline though (where OpenGL itself controls the order things happen in).